# google sheets Split Function

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to split a cell on the 2nd space character.  Is this possible? Or is it just possible to split on a space character?

```
LeBron James SF ORL @ CLEThu 7:00pm

LeBron James        SF ORL @ CLEThu 7:00pm
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try regular expression:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^([^ ]+ [^ ]+) (.*)")`

- `(...) (...)` is to find 2 groups on a string
- `^` at the beginning means to look at the start of a string
- `[^ ]+` means 1+ no space char.
- `.*` means any number of chars

References:

1. [RegexExtract](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)
2. [Regex Syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)

Answer (score 1):

You can use il of individual pieces of the split. For example if 'LeBron James SF ORL @ CLEThu 7:00pm' is in A1. In B1 put this:

```
=index(split(A1," "),0,1)&" "&index(split(A1," "),0,2)
```

It will return 'LeBron James'. In C1 put:

```
=index(split(A1," "),0,3)&" "&index(split(A1," "),0,4)&" "&index(split(A1," "),0,5)&" "&index(split(A1," "),0,6)&" "&text(index(split(A1," "),0,7),"hh:mm am/pm")
```

It will return 'SF ORL @ CLEThu 07:00 PM'. Note the use of text to return the time correctly.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215) the second instance of a space with a character not otherwise in service (I chose `£`), then [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) on that character:

```
 =split(substitute(A1," ","£",2),"£")
```